# Can you use Microsoft Dynamics 4.0 SDK with the .net 4.0 runtime?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, dynamics-crm-4

The Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 SDK provides versions of the dlls compiled against both x86 and x64 architectures, but only for the .net 3.5 runtime.

Does anyone know of versions compiled against .net 4.0, or a work around that would allow for calling the 3.5 versions from 4.0 code?

Answer (score 1):

There are no versions that are compiled against .net 4.0. If you need to use .net 4.0, you will have to use CRM 2011.

Alternatively, if you need to access this from an app written in .net 4.0, you could create a wrapper assembly that reference the CRM assembly in 3.5 and then reference this within your core application, written in 4.0.